# How do you say " 14 days left and will finish the vacation "?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words, verbs

I'm a little bit confused , I tried to find a good answer of how  to say 2 days left +verb 
like 2 days left and will start dieting
or 
2 minutes left and will be ready
or 
14 days left and will finish the fasting 
I tried to find a good translation for what I'm talking about and here it is
(断食終えるまであと14日だよ)
I don't know if it's natural or not ?
please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say about the next event. For example, after the vacation is the exam, so you can say 「試験まであと14日だよ。」(14 days left to the exam) instead.